# Characteristic function problem

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, independence, characteristic-function

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables and suppose also that $X_1$      and $X_1-X_2$ are independent. Show that

$$\mathbb{P}_{X_1}[X_1=c]=1$$

for some constant $c$.

What I get so far is that $\phi(t)\phi(-t)=1$. Then I have problems transforming $\phi(-t)$ to the form of $\phi(t)$. From there, we can get $f(x)$ by integrating $\phi(t)$, but I am not sure I was thinking correctly.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and review its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), modifying your question as necessary.

Comment: Are you assuming that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the _same_ distribution?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Unless you are specifically asked to give a
proof via characteristic functions, consider 
instead that if $X_1$ and $X_1-X_2$ are *independent*, then
they are also *uncorrelated* (that is, their covariance is $0$). Thus, from
the bilinearity of the covariance function and the knowledge that 
$\operatorname{cov}(X,X) = \operatorname{var}(X)$, we have that

$$\operatorname{cov}(X_1, X_1-X_2)
= \operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_1) - \operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2) =
\operatorname{var}(X_1) - 0 = \operatorname{var}(X_1) = 0.$$
So, what can we say about $X_1$ from this result?

---

**Edit:** added in response to @whuber's comment.

I don't have a complete answer when $X$ and $Y$ do not
have a variance and so cannot be said to have a covariance,
but the following is an attempt in that direction

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and
$a$ is a real number such that either $P\{X = a\} > 0$
or $X$ admits of a density at $a$, and this density is continuous
and positive at $X = a$.  Then, consider the following.

1. The *conditional* distribution of $X-Y$ *given* that 
   $X=a$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $a-Y$ *given* 
   that $X = a$.
2. In the special case that $X$ and $Y$ are independent (and thus 
   so are $a-Y$ and $X$ independent
   random variables) the conditional distribution of
   $a-Y$ given $X = a$ is the same as the *unconditional*
   distribution of $a-Y$.
3. From 1. and 2. we have that for *independent* random
   variables $X$ and $Y$, the *conditional* distribution of
   $X-Y$ *given* that $X=a$ is the same as the *unconditional*
   distribution of $a-Y$.  This unconditional distribution depends on
   the value of $a$
4. On the other hand, if $X$ and $Z$ are *independent* random
   variables, then the *conditional* distribution of $Z$ *given*
   that $X=a$ is the same as the *unconditional* distribution
   of $Z$, and this unconditional distribution in no way depends
   of what $a$ is.
5. In the problem at hand, $X=X_1$ and $Y = X_2$ are *independent*
   random variables and thus from 3. we have
   that the *conditional* distribution of
   $X_1-X_2$ given that $X_1 = a$ is the same as the *unconditional*
   distribution of $a-X_2$. This distribution depends on the value of $a$;
   different choices of $a$ result in different distributions.
6. On the other hand, with $X=X_1$ and $Z = X_1-X_2$ being given
   to be *independent* random variables, 4. tells us that the 
   *conditional* distribution of $Z = X_1-X_2$ given $X_1=a$ *does not*
   depend on the value of $a$ at all!

$X_1$ cannot admit of a continuous density since then we would have
more than one $a$ and thus (as per 5.), different conditional distributions 
for $X_1-X_2$ in violation of 6. For the same reason, $X_1$ cannot 
take on two or more values with positive probability. In short,
the only way that 5. and 6. can peacefully co-exist is when
$X_1$ takes on only one value $a$ with probability $1$.

Comment: It's a good hint (+1). I wonder how one would proceed when it is not assumed the variables have variances.

Answer (score 4):

**The question is on the right track.**  Since such a problem evidently is intended to help one understand and work with characteristic functions, I will include many of the details that might otherwise be omitted from the solution.

---

For any random variable $Z$, then, and a real number $t$, let us write

$$\phi_Z(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{i t Z})$$

for the *characteristic function* (cf) of $Z$.  For future reference, note that

$$|\phi_Z(t)| \le \mathbb{E}(|e^{i t Z}|) = \mathbb{E}(1) = 1.$$

It is well known--and easily shown by expanding the exponential into its Taylor series at $0$--that when $\phi_Z$ is differentiable at the origin, its derivatives (divided by suitable powers of $i$) are the moments of $Z$.  Regardless, $\phi_Z$ will be continuous at $0$ (essentially because its behavior there reflects the tails of the distribution of $Z$, which necessarily approach asymptotic values and therefore don't change $\phi_Z(t)$ much for very small $|t|$).

When two variables $(Z_1,Z_2)$ are independent, the characteristic function of a linear combination $\alpha_1 Z_1 + \alpha_2 Z_2$ is neatly related to the cfs of the variables themselves *via*

$$\eqalign{\phi_{\alpha_1Z_1+\alpha_2Z_2}(t)&=\mathbb{E}\left(e^{i t (\alpha_1Z_1+\alpha_2Z_2)}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(e^{i t \alpha_1Z_1}e^{i t \alpha_2Z_2}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(e^{i t \alpha_1Z_1}\right)\mathbb{E}\left(e^{i t \alpha_2Z_2}\right) \\
&=\phi_{Z_1}(\alpha_1 t)\phi_{Z_2}(\alpha_2 t).
}$$

The penultimate equality required independence of the random variables $e^{it\alpha_iZ_i}$, but that is assured by the independence of the $Z_i$.

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent and that $X$ and $X-Y$ are independent, apply this result to a linear combination of $X$ and $X-Y$, say $\alpha X + \beta (X-Y)$, computing it in two ways, using both independence assumptions:

$$\eqalign{\phi_X((\alpha+\beta)t)\phi_Y(-\beta t) &= \phi_{(\alpha+\beta)X-\beta Y}(t)=\phi_{\alpha X+\beta(X-Y)}(t)=\phi_X(\alpha t)\phi_{X-Y}(\beta t) \\
&=\phi_X(\alpha t)\phi_X(\beta t)\phi_Y(-\beta t).
}$$

**This was the key move.**  The desired conclusion follows directly, but some care is needed in the analysis.

The tricky part is that we cannot just divide both sides by $\phi_Y(-\beta t)$, because for many values of $t$ it could be zero.  However, since $\phi_Y(0)=\mathbb{E}(1)=1$ and $\phi_Y$ is continuous at $0$, then for any real $\beta$, $\phi_Y(-\beta t)$ must be nonzero in a neighborhood of zero.  *Within this neighborhood* (which expands as  $|\beta|$ decreases) we may cancel the common $\phi_Y(-\beta t)$ terms appearing at both ends of the preceding series of equations, yielding

$$\phi_X((\alpha+\beta)t) = \phi_X(\alpha t)\phi_X(\beta t).$$

(Setting $\alpha=-\beta=1$ gives $1=\phi_X(0)=\phi_X(t)\phi_X(-t)$, which is the partial result reported in the question.)

Another way to express this is to take logarithms.  For any real number $\gamma$ define the *cumulant generating function* (cgf) as

$$\psi(\gamma) = \log(\phi_X(\gamma)).$$

Since $\phi_X$ is continuous and positive near $0$, $\psi$ is continuous near $0$.  Consider the special case $t=1$ and assume both $|\alpha|$ and $|\beta|$ are small enough that they and $|\alpha+\beta|$ lie in the neighborhood of values $t$ where $\phi_Y(-\beta t)$ is nonzero.  It is immediate that

$$\psi(\alpha+\beta) = \psi(\alpha) + \psi(\beta);\ \psi(0) = 0.$$

It is easy to show that the only such functions are the linear ones.  Thus, there must exist a number $\gamma$ for which

$$\psi(t) = \gamma t$$

for all sufficiently small $t$.  Equivalently, in this neighborhood

$$\phi_X(t) = e^{\gamma t}.$$

Since $|\phi_X(t)| \le 1$ for (sufficiently small) positive *and* negative values of $t$, $\gamma$ must be a purely imaginary number.  Writing it as $\gamma = i c$ for a real number $c$ yields

$$\phi_X(t) = e^{i c t}.$$

Since this is differentiable at the origin, we can now obtain all the moments of $X$.  In particular,

$$\mu_1=\mathbb{E}(X) = \frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{d t} e^{i c t} \vert_{t=0} = c$$

and

$$\mu_2=\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \frac{1}{i^2}\frac{d^2}{d t^2} e^{i c t} \vert_{t=0} = c^2.$$

Therefore the variance of $X$ is

$$\text{Var}(X) = \mu_2 - \mu_1^2 = 0$$

and the desired result follows immediately: **$X$ must be almost everywhere a constant** (equal to the value of $c$ that emerged in the analysis).

Comment: Very educational indeed!  A couple of minor things. Where you say "$\alpha=\beta=1$" I think you meant to say that $\alpha=-\beta=1$.  Also, a characteristic function is essentially a Fourier transform, and Fourier transforms of real functions have the property that $\phi(-t) = [\phi(t)]^*$ and so from $1=\phi(0) = \phi(t)\phi(-t)$ we can immediately deduce that $|\phi(t)|=1$.

Comment: @Dilip Thanks for the correction; I will fix that. I had indeed observed that $|\phi(t)|=1$ but was unable to find a simple way to exploit it.  This troubles me--it would seem one ought to be able to deduce from this that $\phi(t)=\exp(ic t)$.  That's certainly possible by appealing to theorems about the decay of $\phi$ at infinity, but I am wondering whether there is a quick elementary way to make this argument.

Comment: I would appeal to the head of $\phi$. If for nonzero $ t $, $|\phi (t)| = 1$, then $ X $ is discrete with period $2\pi/t $ (Jensen's inequality). So, then if the infimum of all such positive $ t $ is zero, the "period" becomes infinite, i. e., $ X $ is constant almost surely. That is the intuition. The details are only marginally more difficult.